# Laplacian(F) = (n-1/r)g'(r) + g''(r)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I got one more problem from my self reading of Methods of Advanced Calculus by Edwards, hints and solutions are equally appreciated:

If f(x) = g(r), r= |x|, and n>=3, show that 
Laplace(f) = d^2f/dx1^2 +.....+d^2f/dx2^2 = (n-1/r)g'(r) + g''(r)

and using this result show that if Lapace(f) =0 then f(x) = a/|x|^n-2 + b when x does not = 0

Does the n-1 come from the definition of the derivative ?

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: thanks zev, i'll read up on it... I was wonder how people got the good looking formats.

Comment: Can you find $dr/dx_i$? Use the chain and product rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r^2 = ||<x_1,x_2, \dots x_n> ||^2 = x_1^2+x_2^2+ \cdots x_n^2$. Consequently,
$ r \frac{\partial r}{\partial x_j} = x_j $. Consider then, by the chain-rule and the result above:
$$ (\nabla g)_j  = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} g(r) = g'(r)\frac{\partial r }{\partial x_j} = g'(r) \frac{x_j}{r}$$
Now, differentiate once more:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(\nabla g)_j  = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} \left( g'(r) \frac{x_j}{r} \right) = g''(r)\frac{x_j^2}{r^2}+\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}\frac{x_j}{r} = g''(r)\frac{x_j^2}{r^2}+ g'(r)\frac{r-x_j\frac{x_j}{r}}{r^2}$$
cleaning it up a bit:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(\nabla g)_j= g''(r)\frac{x_j^2}{r^2}+ g'(r)\frac{r^2-x_j^2}{r^3}$$
Finally, to find the Laplacian sum the formula above from $j=1,2, \dots n$. It's obvious where the $g''(r)$ term arises. On the other hand, you get $n$ copies of $r^2$ less one copy of $r^2$ from the $g'(r)$ term. Think on this for a bit, you'll see it. Welcome to the MSE.

Comment: i see, this works out well. I think I have got it, will look at it more. I'm glad there is a webpage like this...

Comment: great! Edwards is a lot of fun to work through. I've used it for a course I teach every so often. That problem usually needs a little push for most students. The chain rule is not understood by most students I run across.

Comment: I think their is a typo in $r \frac{\partial r}{\partial x_j} = 2x_j$, there is an extra $2$.

Comment: @user10444 excellent comment. Thanks! Fixed.